# Running this feature file as expected

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, specflow

I have this feature file.

```
Scenario Outline: Verify user can open and view document
Given user is in QueueHandling home page Dashboard
And user has batches assigned to himself/herself 
When user selects "<batchName>" batch from batch list
Then selected batch is opened in a new window
And user views all identified documents

Examples: 
| batchName |
| QGOL2B    |
| QGK3UB    |

Scenario Outline: Verify data in document
When user selects "<documentType>" document and compare data

Examples:
| documentType         |
| Settlement Coversheet|
| AssetLoanAgreement   |

Scenario: Verify user navigates back to QueueHandling home page Dashboard
Given user navigates back to QueueHandling home page Dashboard
```

I want to run it like this.
For QGOL2B batch, I want to execute Verify data in document scenario for both Settlement Coversheet and AssetLoanAgreement.
Then go back and navigate to QGK3UB batch and verify data in document scenario for both Settlement Coversheet and AssetLoanAgreement. How do I achieve?

Comment: "*Is it something I can achieve?*" - the answer to a question like this is typically "yes". Is it truly the question you intended to ask, or is there a better way of wording it?

Comment: Changed the wordings @CaiusJard. Can you help to be implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber makes it really difficult to do things like looping and conditionals in features. This is by design. Features are not for documenting and exploring HOW things are done, they are for documenting WHY things are done and WHAT they are.

Now you have some complex operation, and you want to verify this operation works. What you need to document in this scenario is WHAT this operation is and WHY its important.

So what is the name of the operation that puts a batch through Settlement Coversheet and AssetLoanAgreement. Why is it important to do these things together. Why are they linked. Is the order important etc. etc.

There are lots of questions you need to ask and find answers for. When you have done this you should then be able to write a much simpler scenario.

In general if you want to do something complicated in a scenario, link different scenarios together, loop, run conditional behaviour, or do anything that could be considered programming and you want to do this in features you should STOP and start asking questions.

Every time you start exploring a new piece of behaviour you should be able to write a simple (happy path scenario) like

```
Given I am ready to foo
When I foo
Then I should see I have foo'd
```

If you can't write that initial scenario then Cucumber is telling you that you need to ask questions and understand WHAT you are doing with greater clarity.